# Word - How can I display a section of text from document A in document B that updates in real time when I change it in either document A or B?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editing, microsoft-word-2016, mirroring

Is it possible to display a section e.g. paragraph from document A in multiple other documents (doc B, doc C & D) so that when I edit it in either doc A, doc B, doc C or doc D it updates that paragraph automatically in all the other documents?

These paragraphs often have bullet points as well

At the moment I have been using hyperlinks to get around this problem so when I reach a point in document B where I want to then review a specific paragraph with some bullet points from document A, I have a hyperlink that takes me to a bookmark in document A and I can see / edit that paragraph.

Is it possible to have this section of text from document A embedded in document B so I can just see it and edit it without having to click on the link and physically open document A to view it and edit it there?

Almost like a "live mirror" essentially so it is the same section of text but being embedded in different documents simultaneously?

For example please see this diagram made on paint: [Example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6xDm.jpg)

I'd be really grateful for any advice on how to do this

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Cross-posted in Word Answers forum at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-display-a-section-of-text-from-document/962c766c-5c32-4277-ab5c-3e9989d4d6d1  See this post on the etiquette of cross-posting http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no way to do this built into Word.

**What I would do, instead, is save these provisions in AutoText in a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) and use the [AutoText Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-autotext-field-47082137-225a-4d9e-b74a-5faf6a5f69cb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to insert them in the documents.**

*If you want to modify an AutoText entry, you actually enter the AutoText in a document, modify it, and re-save the entry.*

You will want to update the AutoText field(s) in your documents. This may happen when you print, or not, depending on user settings. Here is a macro that does this.

```
Sub UpdateAllAutoText()
'   Update all AutoText fields in a document, even if in headers/footers or textboxes
    ' https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/word_fields.html
    ' November 12, 2020 Charles Kenyon
    Dim rngstory As Word.range
    Dim lngValidate As Long ' do not know purpose of this - CK
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim oStory As range
    Dim oField As Field

    lngValidate = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).range.StoryType ' do not know purpose of this
    For Each rngstory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
      'Iterate through all linked stories
        For Each oField In oStory.Fields
            If oField.Type = wdFieldAutoText Then oField.Update
        Next oField
      Do
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each oField In rngstory.Fields
            If oField.Type = wdFieldAutoText Then oField.Update
        Next oField
            
        Select Case rngstory.StoryType
          Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
            If rngstory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
              For Each oShp In rngstory.ShapeRange
                If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    For Each oField In oShp.TextFrame.Fields
                        If oField.Type = wdFieldAutoText Then oField.Update
                    Next oField
                End If
              Next
            End If
          Case Else
            'Do Nothing
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Get next linked story (if any)
        Set rngstory = rngstory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngstory Is Nothing
    Next
    '
    Set oStory = Nothing
    Set oField = Nothing
    Set rngstory = Nothing
    Set oShp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Likewise, the field will not work on external computers without access to the template containing the AutoText entries. You would want to unlink the field prior to sending the document out to someone else.

Here is a macro to unlink AutoText fields in a document.

```
Sub UnlinkAllAutoText()
'   Unlink all AutoText fields in a document, even if in headers/footers or textboxes
'   Based on code at http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm
'   Charles Kenyon
'   2 Sept 2020
'
    Dim oStory As range
    Dim oField As Field
    '
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each oField In oStory.Fields
            If oField.Type = wdFieldAutoText Then oField.Unlink
        Next oField
        '
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                For Each oField In oStory.Fields
                    If oField.Type = wdFieldAutoText Then oField.Unlink
                Next oField
            Wend
        End If
        '
    Next oStory
    '
    Set oStory = Nothing
    Set oField = Nothing
End Sub
```

My tendency is to use [document templates](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) that have these fields. When I want a document to send out or print, I create a new document based on the template. The templates have macros that update and unlink the AutoText fields upon document creation. The macros and the AutoNew macro for the document templates is shown in my page on [Boilerplate Language in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoTextFieldMacros).

***Disclosure**: The links about global and document templates go to my web page on Templates in Microsoft Word.*